# Python counting next to one another

Tags: python

I have this code but i would like the numbers to be printed next to one another but it doesn't do that it just prints down the screen instead of filling up the screen.

```
import random
count=2
while count>0:
   print(random.randint(0,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
print(random.randint(0,1))
```

with

```
print(random.randint(0,1), end="").
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html